# React Redux, how to handle form item creation and redirects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I've new to React (and Redux), and trying to make a simple form that will create and ***Item*** (`name, type`), and redirect to the ***ListIems*** page, after creation.

I'm using react-thunk to handle asynchronous actions, and everything is in typescript.

My issue is how to I handle creation results, and redirects? As my action `CreateItemRequest` is asynchronous, how do I inform my containers the Item has been successful created so it redirect to the ***ListIems*** page.

I've tried to simply use a boolean in my `CreateItemSuccess` action my reducer, but then, I can't go to the create form itself, as the boolean is now true is the model, and then immediately redirects to the ***ListIems*** page.

I'm stuck here, I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but can't find anything anywhere...

---

### My component:

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';
import * as React from 'react';

import * as Types from '../../types';
import * as Actions from '../../actions';

interface ICreateModelDispatchProps {
  LoadItems: () => void;
  ChangeForm: (model: Actions.IItemCreateModel) => void;
  CreateItem: (model: Actions.IItemCreateModel) => void;
}

interface ICreateItemStateProps {
  Types: Types.ITypeEntity[];
  ItemCreated: boolean;

  Model: Actions.IItemCreateModel;
}

class CreateItem extends React.Component<ICreateItemStateProps & ICreateModelDispatchProps, Types.IAppState> {
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.props.LoadItems();
  }

  public render() {
    if (this.props.ItemCreated) {
      const redirect = () => <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/items' }} />;
      return <Route render={redirect} />;
    }

    if (!this.props.Types.length) {
      return <div id="create-item" className="loading" />;
    }

    const { Name, Type } = this.props.Model;
    const onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    const onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
    const onTypeChange = this.onTypeChange.bind(this);

    return (
      <div id="create-item">
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" value={Name} placeholder="Item's Name" onChange={onNameChange} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="type">Type</label>
            <select id="type" onChange={onTypeChange} value={Type}>
              <option value="-1">Choose a type</option>
              {this.props.Types.map(type => <option key={type.Id} value={type.Id}>{type.Name}</option>)}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="CREATE" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

  private onNameChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this.props.ChangeForm(Object.assign(this.props.Model, { Name: event.target.value }));
  }

  private onTypeChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    this.props.ChangeForm(Object.assign(this.props.Model, { Type: event.target.value }));
  }

  private onSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.CreateItem(this.props.Model);
  }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state: Types.IAppState): ICreateItemStateProps {
  const types = Object.keys(state.Entities.Types).map(key => state.Entities.Types[Number(key)]);
  const Model = state.CreateItem;

  return {
    Model,
    Types: types,
    ItemCreated: !!state.CreateItem.Created,
  };
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch): ICreateModelDispatchProps {
  return {
    LoadItems: () => dispatch(Actions.ITEM_TYPES_REQUEST()),
    ChangeForm: (model) => dispatch(Actions.ITEM_CREATE_CHANGE(model)),
    CreateItem: (model) => dispatch(Actions.ITEM_CREATE_REQUEST(model)),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateItem);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write your action using `Promise` or `async/await`. Here is example in js (not ts)

```
export default function ITEM_CREATE_REQUEST(model) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      /* SOME STUFF */

      resolve(SOME_DATA);
    });
  }
};
```

than you may use it to navigate when resolved

```
onSubmit() {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.CreateItem(this.props.Model).then((SOME_DATA) => {
    /* PERFORM REDIRECT */
  });
}
```

Comment: That's something I've already saw before, but the Redux or React-Redux typescript definition, doesn't give me a Promise in return of a Dispatch... Even if it is actually a Promise, as I've tested with an `any` type: `CreateItem: (model: Actions.IItemCreateModel) => void;` become `CreateItem: (model: Actions.IItemCreateModel) => any;`, I can't the do the async/then as you propose.

But as It's not in the Typescript definition, I thought it was not a good behavior to use?

Comment: Im not familiar with ts, but I think it is definitely possible to use Promises there. You should find ITEM_CREATE_CHANGE function and play with it in way i shown

Comment: I'm using it the same way as @SashaKos already mentioned. (without ts). My actions creators are mostly API calls and they return Promises. So it's very easy execute something on success or on error.

Comment: I think I understand, but i would like to keep the [recommended async flow for redux](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions). I feel like waiting for Promise in my controller will not respect this principle and may create some weird behavior ?

Comment: That is first thing, that I wanted to advice to you, but your task is pretty strait to move it to redux. BUT if you still want to use redux, you may add some field, I usually call in `pending`. Initially it is null, when you start submitting - you set it to true, when submitting complete - set true. Then in component (componentWillReceiveNewProps) - when `newProps.pending === true` -> navigate

Comment: Do you mean `componentWillReceiveProps()`, which is `UNSAFE` and [should be avoided](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)?

Comment: Oh, Im using react 15, and i didn't know that it became unsave. Thanks. Thats mean, you really should avoid using it. Than you may use componentDidUpdate

Comment: Or may be this guy @Hinrich is right and `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` is good one

Comment: It really feel like using things that are not meant to do what I want :/ I can't believe it's so complicated to do a redirect after an action using redux...

Comment: complexity is relative. When you will work with redux for a few weeks - it will be ok for you. But you still may use approach I gave you, without redux. It is not bad practice to use it it your task

Comment: I do like your approach and think it's the best way to do what I want, but I would like to know how to do so using Redux too

Answer (score 2):

When you dispatch your async action, you update the state of the store at some unpredictable time in the future. Your component has to receive these updates somehow via `mapStateToProps`.

This way you could handle that the props for creating the new item got updated - presumably best inside `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` lifecycle:

```
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.itemCreated !== this.props.itemCreated) {
        // itemCreated could be a counter or something else.
        // For example, you count up after item is created.
        // Whenever that prop changes, you navigate away like this.
        const { history } = this.props
        history.pushState(null, '/anywhere') or
        history.replaceState(null, '/anywhere')
    }
    return null;
}
```

[Here are the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate) for `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`.

Comment: How do I know this is not an update from another action, like `LoadTypes`?

Comment: In fact, seems like componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated. Use getSnapshotBeforeUpdate instead. You receive the previous props, so you can check if certain props changed.

Comment: I've the same issue as before, when I navigate again to this component, the `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` is called, and the props have changed (false => true), so the redirect is made immediately.

Comment: make sure to set proper default props / initial state and reset it in the store once you navigate away, so that you come back with a clean state

Comment: As I'm using Redux, I can only update the state using actions right?

Comment: Beside, I don't feel this is the right place to do a redirect looking at the log?

Comment: Yes, and you can pass the reducer an inital state on creation.

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173377/discussion-between-jbuiss0n-and-hinrich).